# SQL join allowing only one match from each table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, allocation

I have two tables. One table has coupons allocated to each customer and the other table has redemption information for each customer. I essentially need to be left with only the coupons redeemed for each campaign and if the UPC overlaps two campaigns it will be counted for both (but not counted twice within one campaign).  Here's an idea of the redemtion table

```
| customer_id | UPC  | redeem_date_id |
|-------------|------|----------------|
|     1234    | 3456 |       42       |
|     1234    | 3456 |       43       |
|     1234    | 3456 |       44       |
|     1234    | 3456 |       49       |
```

and the table with the coupons allocated looks like

```
 | customer_id | campaign_id | UPC  | print_date_id | expire_date_id |
 |-------------|-------------|------|---------------|----------------|
 |    1234     |      1      | 3456 |      35       |       45       |
 |    1234     |      1      | 3456 |      40       |       50       |
 |    1234     |      2      | 3456 |      41       |       51       |
```

In this example the customer has more redemptions than allocated coupons (because they could've clipped a coupon somewhere etc..) but they could also have more allocated coupons than redemptions.

Obviously if I do a

```
where a.customer_id = b.customer_id and a.upc=b.upc and 
redeem_date_id between print_date_id and expire_date_id
```

I'm going to get way more records back than I need. I don't want the same redemption counted more than once for each campaign, and I don't want more coupons back than I originally had. The exception is, the same redemption can be counted for different campaigns just not within one campaign. (so if the redemption table only had the first observation I would want the output table to have two redemptions - one for either coupon in campaign 1 -- I don't care which -- and one for campaign 2.)

It's really an allocation problem - within a campaign I want to look in the redemption table for a match - join it - then look for a match for the next observation (without reusing the first matching redemption). So one of many possible ways the output table could look is:

```
| customer_id |campaign_id|UPC |print_date_id|expire_date_id|redeem_date_id|
|-------------|-----------|----|-------------|--------------|--------------|
|    1234     |      1    |3456|     35      |        45    |      42      |
|    1234     |      1    |3456|     40      |        50    |      43      |
|    1234     |      2    |3456|     41      |        51    |      42      |
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can the same customer redeem more than 1 coupon for the same `UPC` and the same `campaign` on the same day (i.e. same `redeem_date_id`)?

Comment: Yes, so if you clip two identical coupons and redeem in one transaction it will essentially look like two identical observations in the redemption table. (I could number these observations or something if you're looking for a unique identifier).

Comment: I'm thinking along the lines of using `GROUP BY` to flatten the table but need to preserve the correct `print_date_id` - `expire_date_id` pairs.

Comment: I haven't asked - What is your RDBMS (SQL Flavor)? MySql, SQL Server, Oracle, etc. ?

Comment: Oracle (and I'm extremely new to it)

Answer (score 0):

You could pick the minimal date by using a subquery. Something like:

```
select *
from a inner join b
on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
   and a.upc = b.upc
   and redeem_date_id between print_date_id and expire_date_id
where b.print_date_id = (
   select min(print_date_id)
   from b as b2
   where b2.customer_id = a.customer_id
   and b2.upc = a.upc
   and a.redeem_date_id between b2.print_date_id and b2.expire_date_id
)
```

Though I've not tested it (yet).

But something else is bothering me. Check your coupons

```
 | customer_id | campaign_id | UPC  | print_date_id | expire_date_id |
 |-------------|-------------|------|---------------|----------------|
 |    1234     |      1      | 3456 |      35       |       45       |
```

and your redemption data

```
| customer_id | UPC  | redeem_date_id |
|-------------|------|----------------|
|     1234    | 3456 |       42       |
|     1234    | 3456 |       43       |
```

They don't hold any information to discriminate whether the coupon valid at dates 35-45 was redeemed at date 42 or 43.

In other words, some information appears to be missing: which coupon is it that was redeemed at this time? Is there no unique ID for each coupon? Can you not record that?

I think while it's possible to find a technical solution to your problem today, you're not recording information that is complete enough for this type of application.

Comment: Certainly if every coupon printed had an absolutely unique identifier matching allocated coupons to redemptions would be a breeze. Unfortunately I don't make policy on the coupon industry standards. Generally the barcodes aren't even unique to the specific campaign (part of this problem), let alone every coupon printed.

Comment: OK - sorry I'm on the wrong side of the Atlantic to know that :)

Comment: @GeorgeHarrison, Let me know if the query helps; also the second half of my answer - would edit out but is it of general value to later readers?

Comment: @GeorgeHarrison, another thought, could a coupon have a unique "redeem id" recorded for it at redeem time? That would create the information you need and the problem goes away?

Comment: Sure, I could just effectively add a row number and call it redeem_id but I'm not sure how much that helps.

Comment: @GeorgeHarrison because then you use it as an FK in another table, and keep the information about what coupon is used for what redemption in you DB. No guessing which coupon is used for what by picking the earliest matching one.

Comment: So your query will not get the proper result. It will reuse the earliest eligible coupon for every redemption. The output should not repeat any rows from either table (unless it's a redemption matched to  coupons in different campaigns).

Comment: The output for this example should have 3 rows. The first row of the coupon table matched to any of the first 3 rows of the redemption table. The second row of the coupon table matched to any row in the redemption table (as long as it's not information repeated from the first match). The third row of the coupon table matched to any row in the redemption table (it's a different campaign, so we're not worried about overlap). I know, nice and confusing.

Comment: @GeorgeHarrison you're right, the query's not what you're looking for. But for what you need I think the best solution by far is to record which coupon is used for which redemption by assigning it a redemption value. You can redeem multiple together, but the same coupon can't be used twice, is that right?